# How to test for multiple row actions in a SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql-server, database

My kindergarten SQL Server taught me that a trigger may be fired with multiple rows in the inserted and deleted pseudo tables. I mostly write my trigger code with this in mind, often resulting in some cursor based cludge. Now I'm really only able to test them firing for a single row at a time. How can I generate a multirow trigger and will SQL Server actually ever send a multirow trigger? Can I set a flag so that SQL Server will only fire single row triggers??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if a statement affects more than one row, it should be handled by a single trigger call, as you might want to revert the whole transaction. It is not possible to split it to separate trigger calls logically and I don't think SQL Server provides such a flag. You can make SQL Server call your trigger with multiple rows by issuing an UPDATE or DELETE statement that affects multiple rows.

Comment: I'll go a bit further and say your triggers should ALWAYS take multiple rows into account, whether or not you expect them to be called that way.

Comment: Dave, absolutely. I just wanted to clarify why such a thing should not logically be possible. The trigger should have knowledge about the whole happening "at once" which won't be possible if it ran for every row. Also a DELETE MyTable statement would've taken forever if the trigger is expensive

Comment: @Dave Markle: Totally agree. Would vote up your comment if I could!

Answer (score 10):

Trigger definitions should always handle multiple rows.

Taken from [SQLTeam](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2004/09/14/2077.aspx):

```
-- BAD Trigger code following:

CREATE TRIGGER trg_Table1 
ON Table1 
For UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @var1 int, @var2 varchar(50)

SELECT @var1 = Table1_ID, @var2 = Column2
FROM inserted

UPDATE Table2
SET SomeColumn = @var2
WHERE Table1_ID = @var1
```

**The above trigger will only work for the last row in the inserted table.**

This is how you should implement it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Table1 
ON Table1 
FOR UPDATE
AS

UPDATE t2
SET SomeColumn = i.SomeColumn
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN inserted i
ON t2.Table1_ID = i.Table1_ID
```

Comment: `SET SomeColumn = t1.SomeColumn` seems to be wrong, where is the alias `t1` defined? Nevertheless +1 because now i understand why my trigger was only fired for the last inserted row.

Comment: @Tim: sorry, it was a typo. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

First it concerns me that you are making the triggers handle multiple rows by using a cursor. Do not do that! Use a set-based statment instead jioining to the inserted or deleted pseudotables. Someone put one of those cursor based triggerson our database before I came to work here. It took over forty minutes to handle a 400,00 record insert (and I often have to do inserts of over 100,000 records to this table for one client). Changing it to a set-based solution changed the time to less than a minute. While all triggers must be capable of handling multiple rows, you must not do so by creating a performance nightmare.

If you can write a select statment for the cusor, you can write an insert, update or delete based on the same select statment which is set-based.

Comment: I need to execute the same set of updates after a trigger fires, in 3 different places (triggers). For maintainability reasons I put all the updates into a SP and let the triggers just call the procedure. So I need a cursor here in case of a multi row update ... :|

Comment: You can write a stored proc that uses a table variable as an input variable and performs set-based work. Under no circumstances use a cursor in a trigger.

Comment: Further, performance is far more critical than maintainability. Maintainability should never trump performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've always written my triggers to handle multiple rows, it was my understanding that if a single query inserted/updated/deleted multiple rows then only one trigger would fire and as such you would have to use a cursor to move through the records one by one.

Comment: Don't use a cursor in a trigger, use a set-based statement instead,

Answer (score 0):

One SQL statement always invokes one trigger execution - that's part of the definition of a trigger. (It's also a circumstance that seems to at least once trip up everyone who writes a trigger.) I believe you can  discover how many records are being affected by inspecting @@ROWCOUNT.