# Update Trigger For Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to Insert data in a table named `"Candidate_Post_Info_Table_ChangeLogs"` whenever a record is updated in another table named `"Candidate_Personal_Info_Table"`. my code works fine whenever a single record is updated but when i try to updated multiple rows it gives error:

**"Sub query returned more then 1 value".**

Following is my code :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Candidate_PostInfo_UPDATE]
   ON [dbo].[Candidate_Post_Info_Table]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   RETURN

       DECLARE @Candidate_Post_ID int
       DECLARE @Candidate_ID varchar(50)
       DECLARE @Action VARCHAR(50)
       DECLARE @OldValue VARCHAR(MAX)
       DECLARE @NewValue VARCHAR(MAX)
       DECLARE @Admin_id int

       IF UPDATE(Verified)
       BEGIN
            SET @Action = 'Changed Verification Status'
            SET @Candidate_Post_ID = (Select ID From inserted)
            SET @Candidate_ID = (Select Identity_Number from inserted)
              SET @NewValue = (Select Verified From inserted)
              SET @OldValue = (Select Verified From deleted)
              IF(@NewValue != @OldValue)
              BEGIN
              INSERT INTO  Candidate_Post_Info_Table_ChangeLogs(Candidate_Post_ID, Candidate_ID,  Change_DateTime, action, NewValue, OldValue, Admin_ID)
                VALUES(@Candidate_Post_ID, @Candidate_ID, GETDATE(), @Action,  @NewValue, @OldValue, '1')
                END
       END

END
```

i have searched stack overflow for this issue but couldn't get any related answer specific to this scenario.

Comment: *Really?* If you search on Stack overflow for questions relating to triggers and SQL Server, I'd guess that fully half of them will discuss the fact that you need to treat `inserted` and `deleted` as tables *because* they can contain more than one row.

Comment: you have at least 4 errors. If you insert more than one row INSERTED table has more than one row so you can't write: SET @Candidate_Post_ID = (Select ID From inserted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert/update multiple rows into a table, the `Inserted` temporary table used by the system holds all of the values from all of the rows that were inserted or updated.

Therefore, if you do an update to 6 rows, the `Inserted` table will also have 6 rows, and doing something like this:

```
SET @Candidate_Post_ID = (Select ID From inserted)
```

Will return an error, just the same as doing this:

```
SET @Candidate_Post_ID = (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6)
```

From the looks of things, you tried to do this with an iterative approach.  Set-based is better.  Maybe consider doing it like this in the body of your `TRIGGER` (without all of the parameters...):

```
IF UPDATE(Verified)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Candidate_Post_Info_Table_ChangeLogs 
    (
         Candidate_Post_ID
        ,Candidate_ID
        ,Change_DateTime
        ,action
        ,NewValue
        ,OldValue
        ,Admin_ID
    )
    SELECT 
         I.ID
        ,I.Identity_Number
        ,GETDATE()
        ,'Changed Verification Status'
        ,I.Verified
        ,O.Verified
        ,'1'
    FROM Inserted I
    INNER JOIN Deleted O
        ON I.ID = O.ID -- Check this condition to make sure it's a unique join per row
    WHERE I.Verified <> O.Verified
END
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir. i was confused about how to use a join in this scenario. it solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar case was solved in the following thread using **cursors**.... please check it

[SQL Server A trigger to work on multiple row inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178889/sql-server-a-trigger-to-work-on-multiple-row-inserts)

Also the below thread gives the solution based on **set** based approach

[SQL Server - Rewrite trigger to avoid cursor based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183748/sql-server-rewrite-trigger-to-avoid-cursor-based-approach)

*Both the above threads are from stack overflow...