# Update column in table a base on condition in table b

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger in `Table1` to update a column in `Table2` based on a condition in `Table1`. I am not that good in SQL but enough to be dangerous. This script is not recognizing the column `col2` in `Table1`.

```
Create TRIGGER trgupd on Table1 
After insert
AS 
    If Inserted.col2 = '1'
    BEGIN
        Update Table2
        Set col3 = '2000' + the inserted value
        From Table2
        inner join inserted I on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    End
```

Comment: Well, the biggest issue is: since the trigger might be called once for an entire **batch** of inserts (which might add 25 rows to your table), the check `If Inserted.col2 = '1'` is useless - the `Inserted` table will contain **25 rows** - so which of those are you checing against that `1` value??? It's non-deterministic. You need to **rewrite your triggers** to take into account that `Inserted` *can* (and **WILL!**) contain **multiple rows** having been inserted, when it fires. You **CANNOT** assume there's only a single row in `Inserted`

Comment: what error you get? Invalid Comlumn ?? BTW, you can take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178889/sql-server-a-trigger-to-work-on-multiple-row-inserts to handle multi-row DLM

Comment: The thing is only 1 row is inserted, the program I am using will not give me the option for more than 1. The reason I need to update this column because the value is too small and I need to print it as a barcode. If it's too small then the barcode reader will not read it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it an Update:

```
Create TRIGGER trgupd on Table1 
After insert
AS 
    BEGIN
    Update Table2
    Set col3 = '2000' + the inserted value
    From Table2
    inner join inserted I on I.ID = Table2.ID -- note I.ID not Table1.ID
    where I.col2 = 1;
END
```

The reason yours is failing is that inserted is a table or recordset and `inserted.col2` hasn't actually got a row selected. Just add a `where` clause to your update.

Also, note the join for inserted: Table1 is wrong (it's not in that query); it needs to be I.

Comment: Thank you Simon, 
it installed with no errors however it's not updating the field. If I ran Set col3 = '2000' + the inserted value
by itself in a query it will update the field
Not sure what I am missing